# How do I reduce cpu percentage in portal azure?

Tags: azure, optimization, server, azure-web-app-service, cpu-usage

Right now my website is slow and when I see the xxxx-cd-hp it looks like picture below. CPU: 90, 36%. Is this still normal?

[image]

Apparently at certain times, CPU percentage increased. Maybe because many users have access

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Analyze your application maybe to identify what would cause CPU spike?

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri-AIS How do I know the cause? and what should i do to reduce the percentage of cpu?

Comment: What kind of processing does your web page do?  Is a database involved?

Comment: Will scale up your app service plan pricing tier solve this issue? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-scale-up

Comment: What pricing tier are you using?

Comment: @Rick James Of course. My website using database

Comment: @Tony Ju Seems So I must to scale up my app service plan pricing tier?

Comment: @CSharpRocks Look at this : https://ibb.co/vwBrsST

Comment: @SuccessMan - Have you determined whether the CPU is in the database, or in the web server?  If it is the database, then which (MySQL, etc)?  If database, then the fix may be something simply like adding a better index.  (We need to see the SQL to help with that.)

Comment: Use a larger app service plan, monitor and see if you have the same issues.

Comment: @CSharpRocks What do. you mean "Use a larger app service plan"? I must to scale up my app service plan pricing tier?

Comment: @RickJames Seems that as a whole. Because it is a app service plan

Comment: You're using a B2 plan.  This might not be enough to run Sitecore.

Comment: @CSharpRocks How do you know? Then what do i need to do?

Comment: Sitecore requirements page says the recommended RAM is 8GB https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/81/sitecore-commerce/en/system-requirements.html.  Your plan has 3.5GB.

Comment: @CSharpRocks Okay. So I select B3? But B3 = 7GB